# Migrating Azure Firewall VM

Tags: azure

Currently I have two subscriptions under the same Azure tenancy and I need to know if I can migrate my current firewall VM and SonicWall NSv 200 instance from my current subscription resource group to a new subscription resource group in the same tenancy.

My set up is as follows:
Single tenancy with Subscription A + resource group A containing the Firewall Vm and dependencies and Subscription B with just the resource B empty containers. What is the best way to move the firewall?

Or should I backup the Firewall VM in Subscription A and use disaster recovery to reinstate the Firewall VM in subscription B.

Or can I change the Firewall VM subscription from subscription A to Subscription B ? ( i.e Current firewall subscription is A -- can it be changed to subscription B?.